# Angular standalone components interceptors

Tags: angular

Is any solution for using interceptor providing in standalone component? I've tried just providing it in the component providers section - with no result. Short explanation. I try to use mfe with module federation and remote app has a couple standalone components which need to load programmatically (so i can't get module). There is some http logic in this component. It renders correctly but interceptor doesn't work. I do not attempt to run app with standalone.

type here

```
standalone: true,
    providers: [
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: AuthInterceptor,
            multi: true
        }
    ],
```

Comment: which version of angular you are using?

Comment: obviously greater than 14 or equal

Answer (score 0):

you can add it in the `main.ts` like this:

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
   providers: [
      { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true }
   ]
}
```

if you're using `ngModule` bootstrap you can do it that way:

```
@NgModule({
   providers: [
     { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true }
   ]
 })
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I get it, but like I said I have microfrontend app exposing feature module and standalone component, not app module. So I have to provide interceptor for feature module and somehow for standalone.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open issue related to extend http interceptors in child module. You can view it [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/36974)

Regarding your issue, because you provide new `HTTP_INTERCEPTORS` after creating `HttpClient` instance. When injecting service `HttpClient` from the parent injector, it doesn't see interceptors in child injector.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you are still using Angular 14 then you might need a different solution than proposed above (this is what worked for me). I had to move my http call to an angular service that is provided in root like this:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class DownloadService {
  getImage(imageId: string) {
    return this.httpClient.get(...);
}
```

And then call if from my standalone component like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-logo',
  template: `
    ...
  `,
  standalone: true
})
export class LogoComponent {
  constructor(private downloadService: DownloadService) {}
  getImage(imageId: string) {
    this.downloadService.getImage(imageId)
    .subscribe(...);
  }
};
```

This made so my interceptors set in my main app.module.ts (like below) were finally being called:

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    ...
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: UnauthorizedInterceptor, multi: true }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor() {
  }
}
```